# WP7 - XmlException - Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

Having trouble working out why my xml updates are failing on IsolatedStorage and was wondering if anyone else has had a similar problem.

I'm trying to update a file by iterating through all certain nodes and updating them individually.

For some reason, it fails half way through and then states the data is invalid at root level and that the invalid data is at the end of the file???

The code is as follows:

I make a call to the Update method for every exercise:

```
    foreach (var exercise in program.Exercises)
    {
        UpdateExercise(program, exercise, true);
    }
```

Which uses a static property and calls the data source's Update method:

```
    public void UpdateExercise(WorkoutProgram program, Exercise entity, bool isConversionUpdate)
    {
        ProgramDataSource.Update(program, entity, isConversionUpdate);
    }
```

This method is then called and fails after a few loops at this line: 'root = XElement.Load(XmlReader.Create(fs));'

```
    public void Update(WorkoutProgram program, Exercise exercise, bool isConversionUpdate)
    {
        SetupProgramSource(program);
        XElement root;

        if (!isConversionUpdate)
            exercise.ChangeDate = DateTime.Now;

        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!store.FileExists(_exerciseFile))
            {
                throw new NotFoundException("The file does not exist!");
            }

            using (var fs = store.OpenFile(_exerciseFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                root = XElement.Load(XmlReader.Create(fs));
                var element = root.Element("Exercises").Elements("Exercise").Where(e => e.Element("ID").Value.ToLower().Equals(exercise.ID.ToString().ToLower())).Single();
                element.SetElementValue("Description", exercise.Description);
                element.SetElementValue("Name", exercise.Name);
                var exerciseChanges = element.Element("ExerciseChanges");

                if (exercise is AnaerobicExercise)
                {
                    var anaerobicExercise = exercise as AnaerobicExercise;
                    element.SetElementValue("Reps", anaerobicExercise.Repetitions);
                    element.SetElementValue("Sets", anaerobicExercise.Sets);
                    element.Element("Weight").SetElementValue("Amount", anaerobicExercise.Weight.Amount);
                    element.Element("Weight").SetElementValue("Measurement", anaerobicExercise.Weight.Measurement);
                    ...                    
                }

                if (exercise is AerobicExercise)
                {
                    var aerobicExercise = exercise as AerobicExercise;
                    element.SetElementValue("Distance", aerobicExercise.Distance);
                    element.Element("Duration").SetAttributeValue("hours", aerobicExercise.Duration.Hours);
                    element.Element("Duration").SetAttributeValue("minutes", aerobicExercise.Duration.Minutes);
                    element.Element("Duration").SetAttributeValue("seconds", aerobicExercise.Duration.Seconds);
                    element.SetElementValue("Measurement", aerobicExercise.Measurement);

                    if (!isConversionUpdate)
                    {
                        var exerciseChange = exercise.Changes.OfType<AerobicExerciseChange>().FirstOrDefault(ec => ec.ChangeDate.Date == exercise.ChangeDate.Date);

                        if (exerciseChange != null)
                        {
                            var changesElement = exerciseChanges.Elements("Changes").First(x => x.Attribute("id").Value.ToLower().Equals(exerciseChange.ID.ToString().ToLower()));
                            changesElement.SetAttributeValue("hours", aerobicExercise.Duration.Hours);
                            changesElement.SetAttributeValue("minutes", aerobicExercise.Duration.Minutes);
                            changesElement.SetAttributeValue("seconds", aerobicExercise.Duration.Seconds);
                            changesElement.SetAttributeValue("distance", aerobicExercise.Distance);
                            var change = exercise.Changes.OfType<AerobicExerciseChange>().First(ec => ec.ChangeDate.Date == exercise.ChangeDate.Date);
                            change.Duration = aerobicExercise.Duration;
                            change.Distance = aerobicExercise.Distance;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var changeDate = new XAttribute("changeDate", string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", aerobicExercise.ChangeDate));
                            var typeAttribute = new XAttribute("type", "Aerobic");
                            var hoursAttribute = new XAttribute("hours", aerobicExercise.Duration.Hours);
                            var minutesAttribute = new XAttribute("minutes", aerobicExercise.Duration.Minutes);
                            var secondsAttribute = new XAttribute("seconds", aerobicExercise.Duration.Seconds);
                            var distanceAttribute = new XAttribute("distance", aerobicExercise.Distance);
                            var changesElement = new XElement("Changes");
                            exerciseChange = WorkoutManagerEntityFactory.GetEntityChange<AerobicExerciseChange>();
                            var idAttribute = new XAttribute("id", exerciseChange.ID.ToString());
                            changesElement.Add(idAttribute, typeAttribute, hoursAttribute, minutesAttribute, secondsAttribute, distanceAttribute, changeDate);
                            exerciseChanges.Add(changesElement);
                            exerciseChange.ChangeDate = aerobicExercise.ChangeDate;
                            exerciseChange.Distance = aerobicExercise.Distance;
                            exerciseChange.Duration = aerobicExercise.Duration;
                            aerobicExercise.Changes.Add(exerciseChange);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var aerobicExerciseChange in exercise.Changes.OfType<AerobicExerciseChange>())
                        {
                            var changesElement = exerciseChanges.Elements("Changes").First(x => x.Attribute("id").Value.ToLower().Equals(aerobicExerciseChange.ID.ToString().ToLower()));
                            changesElement.SetAttributeValue("hours", aerobicExercise.Duration.Hours);
                            changesElement.SetAttributeValue("minutes", aerobicExercise.Duration.Minutes);
                            changesElement.SetAttributeValue("seconds", aerobicExercise.Duration.Seconds);
                            changesElement.SetAttributeValue("distance", aerobicExercise.Distance);
                            var change = exercise.Changes.OfType<AerobicExerciseChange>().First(ec => ec.ID == aerobicExerciseChange.ID);
                            change.Duration = aerobicExercise.Duration;
                            change.Distance = aerobicExercise.Distance;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var fs = store.OpenFile(_exerciseFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                root.Save(fs);
            }
        }
    }
```

The XML (reduced version with most exercise nodes removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Program name="Strength Training">
  <ID>2eec20d2-a278-11df-bc86-00138f82a706</ID>
  <Duration hours="0" minutes="39" seconds="0" />
  <Description>Main workout program for general all over fitness</Description>
  <Exercises>
    <Exercise exerciseType="Aerobic">
      <ID>6E391E75-E75C-49CA-95FC-FEDF03D3ED1A</ID>
      <Name>Treadmill Run</Name>
      <Description>With a bar-bell on your back, feet shoulder width apart, back straight, knees slightly bent and in line with the feet, slowly go down and then back up. Squats develop power and strength.</Description>
      <Distance>4</Distance>
      <Duration hours="0" minutes="10" seconds="0" />
      <Measurement>Kilometres</Measurement>
      <ExerciseChanges>
        <Changes id="291C3CCA-9997-4B4E-A1D5-75129DBB2638" type="Aerobic" hours="0" minutes="10" seconds="0" distance="4" changeDate="27/11/2010" />
      </ExerciseChanges>
    </Exercise>
    <Exercise exerciseType="Anaerobic">
      <ID>2eec20c5-a278-11df-bc86-00138f82a706</ID>
      <Name>Squats</Name>
      <Description>With a bar-bell on your back, feet shoulder width apart, back straight, knees slightly bent and in line with the feet, slowly go down and then back up. Squats develop power and strength.</Description>
      <Reps>10</Reps>
      <Weight>
        <Amount>130</Amount>
        <Measurement>Kilograms</Measurement>
      </Weight>
      <Sets>1</Sets>
      <ExerciseChanges>
        <Changes id="D20A177E-BC23-49B0-99CD-1F467590A996" type="Anaerobic" amount="130" sets="1" reps="10" changeDate="27/11/2010" />
      </ExerciseChanges>
    </Exercise>
    <Exercise exerciseType="Anaerobic">
      <ID>2eec20d1-a278-11df-bc86-00138f82a706</ID>
      <Name>Abs</Name>
      <Description>With a bar-bell on your back, feet shoulder width apart, back straight, knees slightly bent and in line with the feet, slowly go down and then back up. Squats develop power and strength.</Description>
      <Reps>15</Reps>
      <Weight>
        <Amount>0</Amount>
        <Measurement>Kilograms</Measurement>
      </Weight>
      <Sets>1</Sets>
      <ExerciseChanges>
        <Changes id="FFF2FF28-607F-465E-8BAC-B4F21E568253" type="Anaerobic" amount="0" sets="1" reps="15" changeDate="27/11/2010" />
      </ExerciseChanges>
    </Exercise>
  </Exercises>
  <ProgramChanges>
    <Duration id="0BA96209-CF3C-4E85-8EB5-3BEE6A2DB118" hours="0" minutes="45" seconds="0" changeDate="27/11/2010" />
    <Duration id="DAEEE9DF-A155-48AC-A5CE-09D738947C76" hours="0" minutes="39" seconds="0" changeDate="28/11/2010" />
  </ProgramChanges>
</Program>
```

The encoding is UTF-8 without BOM.

Anyone seen this before?

All thoughts are appreciated (even ones saying my code's crap and needs refactoring).

EDIT:

Problem with adding: InvalidOperationException - The Parent is missing:

```
    private static XElement GetExerciseElement(Exercise entity)
    {
        var exerciseElement = new XElement("Exercise");

        if (entity is AnaerobicExercise)
        {
            var anaerobicExercise = entity as AnaerobicExercise;
            var exerciseTypeAttribute = new XAttribute("exerciseType", "Anaerobic");
            var amountElement = new XElement("Amount", anaerobicExercise.Weight.Amount);
            var measurementElement = new XElement("Measurement", anaerobicExercise.Weight.Measurement);
            var weightElement = new XElement("Weight");
            var nameElement = new XElement("Name", anaerobicExercise.Name);
            var descriptionElement = new XElement("Description", anaerobicExercise.Description);
            var repsElement = new XElement("Reps", anaerobicExercise.Repetitions);
            var setsElement = new XElement("Sets", anaerobicExercise.Sets);
            var idElement = new XElement("ID", anaerobicExercise.ID);
            var exerciseChangesElement = new XElement("ExerciseChanges");
            weightElement.Add(amountElement, measurementElement);
            var exerciseChange = new AnaerobicExerciseChange
                                     {
                                         ChangeDate = entity.ChangeDate,
                                         Amount = anaerobicExercise.Weight.Amount,
                                         Sets = anaerobicExercise.Sets,
                                         Repetitions = anaerobicExercise.Repetitions
                                     };
            entity.Changes.Add(exerciseChange);
            exerciseElement.Add(exerciseTypeAttribute, idElement, nameElement, descriptionElement, repsElement, weightElement, setsElement);
            exerciseChangesElement.ReplaceWith(GetExerciseChanges(entity, exerciseElement, exerciseChange));
            exerciseElement.Add(exerciseChangesElement);
        }
```

This line in particular:

```
exerciseChangesElement.ReplaceWith(GetExerciseChanges(entity, exerciseElement, exerciseChange));
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a sample fragment of the xml that is generated?

Comment: My bad! I'll Add the XML file. It should just update element and attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you deleting the existing file before saving the new version?

If you're updated XML is smaller than the original then the end of the original data may be left when you write the new data. This will lead to extra characters at the end of your file which will invalidate the XML.

Comment: try that then. You can check if this is the issue by looking at `fs` when you first load it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem with deleting and then adding (not updating as the file no longer exists) is I'd need to store all data in memory, including ID's and then override the Add method. Also, when I try add I get an InvalidOperationException: The Parent is missing, at the line added above.

Comment: Is it possible to just remove any invalid xml at the end of the doc?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a "Ignore anything at the end once you've parsed a valid xml document" setting. You could try doing this yourself. You're probably better off making sure the data doesn't get corrupt in the first place though.

Comment: Cheers Matt, I'm gonna refactor as it's due anyway. Should hopefully highlight the problem.

Comment: Overloaded the Add method in the end (instead of being lazy). So the solution is as you say, delete the file, then add it again. Microsoft should add a method to remove invalid data at the end of a doc! If you pass in the root node to the method, anything outside should be removed :/

Comment: @Billy When you update the file use `FileMode.Create` (rahter than open) as this has the effect of deleting the existing file first.

Comment: I should of thought of that... doh! On the next refactor I'll try that. Cheers.